# Implementing the merge sort with only arrays, out of place

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

This has been asked a few times here, but I was wondering what I could do to improve the efficiency and readability of my code. My programming skill has gotten rusty, so I would like to elicit all constructive criticism that can make me write code better.

**init:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

**merge()**

```
//The merge function
void merge(int a[], int startIndex, int endIndex)
{

int size = (endIndex - startIndex) + 1;
int *b = new int [size]();

int i = startIndex;
int mid = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;
int k = 0;
int j = mid + 1;

while (k < size)
{   
    if((i<=mid) && (a[i] < a[j]))
    {
        b[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    else
    {
        b[k++] = a[j++];
    }

}

for(k=0; k < size; k++)
{
    a[startIndex+k] = b[k];
}

delete []b;

}
```

**merge_sort()**

```
//The recursive merge sort function
void merge_sort(int iArray[], int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
int midIndex;

//Check for base case
if (startIndex >= endIndex)
{
    return;
}   

//First, divide in half
midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;

//First recursive call 
merge_sort(iArray, startIndex, midIndex);

//Second recursive call 
merge_sort(iArray, midIndex+1, endIndex);

//The merge function
merge(iArray, startIndex, endIndex);

}
```

**main()**

```
//The main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int iArray[10] = {2,5,6,4,7,2,8,3,9,10};

merge_sort(iArray, 0, 9);

//Print the sorted array
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << iArray[i] << endl;
}

return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Fixed indentation as it was imposable to read without it.

Comment: @LokiAstari: As much as I dislike the indentation issue as well, it is not from tabs and I have already reviewed it.  You may keep a better version for yourself if you're going to review it.

Comment: your code could be improved further but i think its an really good [merge sorting c++](http://www.hellgeeks.com/merge-sort/) code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything Jamal said (so I will not repeat)

Plus:

The normal idium in C++ for passing ranges is `[beg, end)`.
For those not mathematically inclined end is specified one past the end.

If you follow the C++ convention you make it easier for other C++ devs to keep track without having to think to hard about what you are up to. Personally I think it also makes writting merge sort easier.

```
 merge_sort(iArray, 0, 10);
```

Then in merge()

```
 midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;     // The start of the second half
                                           // Is one past the end of the first half.
 merge_sort(iArray, startIndex, midIndex);
 merge_sort(iArray, midIndex,   endIndex);
```

Slight optimization here:

```
//Check for base case
if (startIndex >= endIndex)
{
    return;
}
```

You can return if the size is 1. A vector of 1 is already sorted. Since `end` is one past the end the size is `end-start`.

```
if ((endIndex - startIndex) <= 1)
{
    return;
}
```

Don't do manually memory management in your code.

```
int *b = new int [size](); // Also initialization costs.
                           // So why do that if you don't need to!

// PS in C++ (unlike C)
// It is more common to put '*' by the type.
// That's becuase the type is `pointer to int`
```

Better alternative:

```
std::vector<int> b(size);  // Memory management handled for you.
                           // Its exception safe (so you will never leak).
                           // Overhead is insignificant.
```

A conditional in the middle of a loop is expensive.

```
while (k < size)
{
    if((i<=mid) && (a[i] < a[j]))
    {...} else {...}
}
```

Once one side is used up break out of the loop and just copy the other one.

```
while (i <= mid && j <= endIndex)
{    b[k++] = (a[i] < a[j]) ? a[i++] : a[j++];
}
// Note: Only one of these two loop will execute.
while(i <= mid)
{    b[k++] = a[i++];
}
while(j <= endIndex)
{    b[k++] = a[j++];
}
```

Rather than calculating the mid point both in `merge()` and in `merge_sort`, it may be worth just passing the value as a parameter.

Learn to do the inplace merge so you don't have to copy the values back after the merge.

```
 midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;
 merge_sort(iArray, startIndex, midIndex);
 merge_sort(iArray, midIndex,   endIndex);
 merge(iArray, startIndex, midIndex, endIndex);
 //                        ^^^^^^^^   pass midIndex so you don't need to re-calc
```

Answer (score 4):

- [Try not to use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- Code within a function should be indented as well.  You already do this with other code blocks, and the same applies to functions.
- Just avoid Hungarian notation:

  ```
  int iArray;
  ```

  We already know it's an `int` array.
- Prefer not to pass C arrays to functions in C++.  This causes them to decay to a pointer; it does not actually pass the array itself.

  Instead, pass in a storage container, such as an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  Storage containers will *not* decay to a pointer, and they're more idiomatic C++.

  If you have C++11, initialize the vector using [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

  ```
  std::vector<int> values { 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 10 };
  ```

  If you don't have C++11, declare it and call `push_back()` for each value:

  ```
  std::vector<int> values;

  values.push_back(2);
  values.push_back(5);
  // ...
  ```

  Pass it to a function with such parameters:

  ```
  void merge_sort(std::vector<int> values, int startIndex, int endIndex) {}
  ```

  As its implementation is that of an array, you can still access its elements with `[]`.  You can also use its iterators (more preferred).

  Storage containers do the memory allocation for you, so you will not need `new`/`delete`.  It's best to do as little manual memory allocation as possible in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the interesting points has been covered already. The missing one:

`merge` is an important algorithm of its own. As implemented, it imposes very harsh and non-obvious preconditions. Relax them:

```
void merge(int b[], int a0[], int size0, int a1[], int size1);
```

and let the caller decide how to allocate/delete/reuse the `b` array. Notice that in the context of `mergesort` the caller is *you*, so the caller of `mergesort` wouldn't see the difference.

PS: a *no raw loops* rule is also perfectly applicable. A loop:

```
for(k=0; k < size; k++)
{
    a[startIndex+k] = b[k];
}
```

in fact implements an important algorithm known as `copy(int * a, int * b, int size)`, and is better be factored out as such.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this. Read about the no raw loops rule just now, and it makes sense.